# SteamCMD - App state is 0x602 after update job

Tags: error-handling, electron, steam

I'm trying to develop a desktop application that will simplify some of the process of SteamCMD, so the user will just use a GUI to interact with SteamCMD.
Except, I ran into a strange problem:
If I'm using SteamCMD directly, I can download the files of app ID 740 (Counter-Strike: Global Offensive Dedicated Server).
If I'm using SteamCMD indirectly, on the other hand, i.e. my application will spawn a process `steamcmd.exe +login anonymous +app_update 740` - I'm getting an error of `Error! App '740' state is 0x602 after update job`.
[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Error!+App+%27740%27+state+is+0x602+after+update+job) does provide some information, as some users encountered the error as well when they tried to do different stuff, but the solution didn't apply to me.

Comment: That code (`0x602`) seems to be related to network issues -- see [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/GameServerManagers/LinuxGSM/issues/719#issuecomment-330470766) on a project built upon SteamCMD.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, since my internet is stable and its download rate is ~920Mb/s

Comment: What's even weirder, is that my program can successfully download a Garry's Mod dedicated server, and even a Team Fortress 2 dedicated server, but it can't even begin downloading a Counter-Strike: Global Offensive dedicated server

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only difference between the packages you have stated and CS:GO dedicated server is that CS:GO DS has the `VisibleOnlyWhenInstalled` attribute set (see [SteamDB](https://steamdb.info/app/740/info/)). Do you use SteamCMD logged in to your account or do you also use `login anonymous` (this will not work for some servers, see the [SteamCMD doc](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD#SteamCMD_Login))?

Comment: Like I mentioned in my main post, I'm logging in anonymously. Also, as I mentioned in the first post, I _am_ able to download the CS:GO server, when I'm using SteamCMD _directly_. The download only fails when I try to download the CS:GO server by executing SteamCMD's process with the parameters.

Comment: Well, it wasn't clear that you also use `login anonymous` when using SteamCMD directly. Also, this seems particularly odd and may be a bug.

Comment: Well, who do I report the bug to? Nobody seems to be in charge of the software. Recently I created a ticket in Steam Support, and the support representative suggested me to post my problem to the Steam Community Discussions. Not exactly professional help.

Comment: Maybe some developer will read through these community discussions, but this is just an educated guess. So far, I don't see anything you could do...

Comment: A discussion on the official Steam Community is far more likely to get noticed by a Steam dev who would know who to talk to about it. That's probably why support pointed you there. Is the output from the program up until the point where it fails the same both when used directly and when automated?

Comment: No. That's exactly the problem. When I use it directly, it's working flawlessly. When I run SteamCMD with the flags that supposedly lead to downloading the files, however - the SteamCMD process crashes with the error mentioned in the first post.

Answer (score 0):

Either delete the Steam app and run the Steam updater or uninstall and install the game.